# App crashes when reopening

Tags: javascript, java, android

I build my app with Android Studio

The app works great when testing. But when i close my app and what to restart it again it won't work. Only when i go to settings (cell Phone) and clear data it will restart. Help me please.

```
package remco.politiewillemiiapp;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_algemeen_toestand) {
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.content_frame
               , new Algemeen_Toestand())
               .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_algemeen_opdracht) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Algemeen_Opdracht())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_algemeen_uitvoering) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Algemeen_Uitvoering())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_algemeen_verzoring) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Algemeen_Verzorging())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_algemeen_tunue) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Algemeen_Tunue())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_algemeen_bevelvoering) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Algemeen_Bevelvoering())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_algemeen_scenario) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Algemeen_Scenario())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_operationeel_wedstrijdinformatie) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Operationeel_Wedstrijdinformatie())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_operationeel_tijdsschema) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Operationeel_Tijdsschema())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_operationeel_indeling) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Operationeel_Indeling())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_operationeel_verbindingsschema) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Operationeel_Verbindingsschema())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_operationeel_stdaion) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Operationeel_Stadion())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_operationeel_positie) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Operationeel_Positie())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_operationeel_aanhoudingskaart) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Operationeel_Aanhoudingskaart())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_operationeel_stdionverboden) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Operationeel_Stadionverboden())
                .commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

```
04-08 16:56:10.992 6481-6481/? E/Zygote: v2
04-08 16:56:10.992 6481-6481/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10371
04-08 16:56:10.992 6481-6481/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
04-08 16:56:10.992 6481-6481/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-G920F_5.1.1 ver=38
04-08 16:56:10.992 6481-6481/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0004
04-08 16:56:11.002 6481-6481/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-08 16:56:11.002 6481-6481/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=remco.politiewillemiiapp 
04-08 16:56:11.002 6481-6481/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-08 16:56:11.032 6481-6481/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
04-08 16:56:11.032 6481-6481/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
04-08 16:56:11.042 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/remco.politiewillemiiapp-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in remco.politiewillemiiapp rsrc of package remco.politiewillemiiapp
04-08 16:56:11.052 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
04-08 16:56:11.052 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
04-08 16:56:11.052 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
04-08 16:56:11.052 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/remco.politiewillemiiapp-2/lib/arm64
04-08 16:56:11.052 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
04-08 16:56:11.052 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap remco.politiewillemiiapp
04-08 16:56:11.052 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/InjectionManager: Constructor remco.politiewillemiiapp, Feature store :{}
04-08 16:56:11.052 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
04-08 16:56:11.062 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/remco.politiewillemiiapp-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in remco.politiewillemiiapp rsrc of package remco.politiewillemiiapp
04-08 16:56:11.062 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/remco.politiewillemiiapp-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in remco.politiewillemiiapp rsrc of package remco.politiewillemiiapp
04-08 16:56:11.172 6481-6502/remco.politiewillemiiapp D/skia: ---- fAsset->read(2769) returned 0
04-08 16:56:11.382 6481-6491/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 263MB to 256MB
04-08 16:56:11.392 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-08 16:56:11.392 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-08 16:56:11.392 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-08 16:56:11.392 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 263MB to 256MB
04-08 16:56:11.392 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-08 16:56:11.402 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 263MB to 256MB
04-08 16:56:11.402 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 247MB/256MB, paused 107us total 7.813ms
04-08 16:56:11.402 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 16MB allocation
04-08 16:56:11.402 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-08 16:56:11.412 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 263MB to 256MB
04-08 16:56:11.412 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(352B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 247MB/256MB, paused 106us total 6.437ms
04-08 16:56:11.412 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 16777228 byte allocation with 8830256 free bytes and 8MB until OOM"
04-08 16:56:11.412 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-08 16:56:11.412 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-08 16:56:11.422 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-08 16:56:11.422 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 263MB to 256MB
04-08 16:56:11.422 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-08 16:56:11.432 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 263MB to 256MB
04-08 16:56:11.432 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 247MB/256MB, paused 111us total 6.567ms
04-08 16:56:11.432 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 16MB allocation
04-08 16:56:11.432 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
04-08 16:56:11.432 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 263MB to 256MB
04-08 16:56:11.432 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 247MB/256MB, paused 105us total 6.500ms
04-08 16:56:11.442 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 16777228 byte allocation with 8830256 free bytes and 8MB until OOM"
04-08 16:56:11.442 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
04-08 16:56:11.442 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-08 16:56:11.452 6481-6481/remco.politiewillemiiapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: remco.politiewillemiiapp, PID: 6481
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{remco.politiewillemiiapp/remco.politiewillemiiapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                        at remco.politiewillemiiapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                        at remco.politiewillemiiapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                        at remco.politiewillemiiapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16777228 byte allocation with 8830256 free bytes and 8MB until OOM
                                                                        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2005)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987)
                                                                        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:464)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
                                                                        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.appendTransparentIconIfMissing(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:519)
                                                                        at
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: Post the logcat to help you

Comment: Post your errors, Uff.. a lot of `if/else`, you should use `switch` instad of `if/else`.

Comment: @AntonioTejada logcat is now included

Comment: @Aspicas just replace if/else with switch?

Comment: Looks like you have an inflating problem:

**android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView**

Can you add the activity_main.xml code also?

Comment: @AntonioTejada activity_main is added

Comment: @AntonioTejada i also have activity_main_drawer.xml but i can't add this one because the to many characters for the body

Comment: Which Android support version are you working with? Because if it is v.23.1.0 it has a bug with the NavigationView.

If not, tell me which version are you currently using,

Comment: @AntonioTejada where can i find the android support version?

Comment: In the build.gradle file

Comment: @AntonioTejada Android studio version 1.5.1 and a update availible for android 2.0

Comment: @AntonioTejada buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: I meant the Android Support Library not the build tools, but it is good to know that version too. Check out the support library please.

Comment: And also tell me what do you have in your **nav_header_main** layout, that could be the main problem.

app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"

Comment: @AntonioTejada com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
   'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

Comment: @AntonioTejada i posted the nav_header_main

Comment: Try putting both on '23.0.1' version and let me know what happens.

Comment: Wow it works! Thanks

Comment: @AntonioTejada can you help me with another problem? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778881/app-crash-with-webview) Thank you very much

Comment: I will put my comment as an answer so you can accept it. Glad it finally helped you  :)

Comment: @RemcovandenDungen

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/willem1"
        android:layout_weight="0.55" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Politie Willem II App"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wedstrijd en Algemeen draaiboek"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put both your

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1' 
'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

to version

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1' 
'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

to finally make it work.

Comment: @RemcovandenDungen